# Add and retrieve Audio file using LDAP protocol

Tags: file-upload, ldap, download, ldapconnection

I want to know the details about how to add and retrieve an audio file using the LDAP protocol?

Is it possible? If, then how does it work?

Can anyone help me please providing the details?

Answer (score 1):

The LDAP protocol doesn't read or write files.

The question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry .. it will be  add and retrieve an audio file using the LDAP protocol